# How to run a command in background with no output unless there's an error

Tags: shell, fish

How to suppress a command's output but show it if the command exit codes an error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, the assumption that `stderr` is only used for error output isn't always correct. Rather, `stderr` is often used for any and all *interactive* output and diagnostics, i.e. output intended for the user to read in an interactive prompt<sup>1</sup>. `wget` and `dd` are well-known examples.

Some commands will provide a flag (e.g. `-quiet` or `-silent`) to suppress non-error output - read their man pages to see if one exists.

---

Another convention that holds more often is the **exit code**: a program returns an exit code when it exits. Typically<sup>2</sup>, an exit code of `0` indicates success, and any other exit code indicates an error.

With `bash`, you can get the exit code of the last command from the `$?` variable. In `fish`, use the `$status` variable. You can pipe `stderr` to a temporary file and only print it if an error occurs. For example (`fish`):

```
command 2>/tmp/outputbuffer
if $status
    cat /tmp/outputbuffer
rm /tmp/outputbuffer
```

You can also use some shortcuts, if you aren't chaining commands:

```
if command 2>/tmp/outputbuffer
    cat /tmp/outputbuffer
rm /tmp/outputbuffer
```

Or:

```
command 2>/tmp/outputbuffer; or cat /tmp/outputbuffer; rm /tmp/outputbuffer;
```

You can also pipe `stdout` to the same buffer by using `2>&1 >/tmp/outputbuffer`.

(Note: I don't actually know `fish`, so I'm adapting the concept to what I can find in its documentation. The syntax might be slightly wrong. Also, you can use `mktemp` to generate a unique temporary file - run it and record the filename in a variable.)

If you need to run the whole thing in the background of a shell you are also using interactively at the same time, then you're better off writing a script to handle the output-hiding and running that script in the background with the [standard techniques](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait) ([`fish`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/#syntax-background)). Heck, you can put something like the following function in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
function run-silent
    set temp (mktemp)
    if $argv 2>&1 >$temp
        cat $temp
    rm $temp
end
```

Call with `run-silent somecommand &` (where the trailing `&` causes it to run in the background)

Note that this will swallow the original exit code, and will dump both `stdout` and `stderr` in the event of a failure. You can customise it as necessary.

---

<sup>1</sup> There isn't even a guarantee that error output won't appear on `stdout` - some programs will dump all output there!

<sup>2</sup> Unfortunately, this still isn't always the case - the exit code is completely controlled by the program, and some will indicate some success conditions with non-zero exits. Again, check the manual.

Comment: slight fish tweak, there's a special place for putting functions in ~/.config/fish/functions/

Answer (score 13):

Unix utilities send general messages to `stdout`, and error messages to `stderr`, so if we only want to see error messages, then it will be sufficient to suppress `stdout` so only `stderr` gets output to the console.

The way to do this (in both `bash` and `fish`) is to append `>/dev/null` to the command. This pipes stdout into nothingness, but stderr (with your error messages) still comes through to the console.

So for instance:

The command `echo 1 >/dev/null` prints nothing, because the normal `stdout` output is suppressed, and nothing was written to stderr.

The command `man doesnotexist >/dev/null` prints an error message, because `man` writes its error message to `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

This will run the command in the background and write errors to a log file whilest ignoring normal output

```
    command > /dev/null 2> /tmp/example_error.log &
```